# Nvidia Docker installation error in AWS DLAMI with a p2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, nvidia-docker

I am getting the following error while trying to install `nvidia-docker` using the command `sudo yum install nvidia-docker2` (referring [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/batch-gpu-ami.html) & [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Installation-(version-2.0)#installing-version-20)) inside an Amazon deep learning AMI running on a `p2.xlarge` instance:

```
Error: Package: nvidia-docker2-2.0.3-1.docker18.03.1.ce.amzn1.noarch (nvidia-docker)
           Requires: docker = 18.03.1ce
           Installed: docker-17.12.1ce-1.135.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-updates)
               docker = 17.12.1ce-1.135.amzn1
           Available: docker-17.03.2ce-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               docker = 17.03.2ce-1.59.amzn1
           Available: docker-17.06.2ce-1.93.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               docker = 17.06.2ce-1.93.amzn1
           Available: docker-17.06.2ce-1.94.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               docker = 17.06.2ce-1.94.amzn1
           Available: docker-17.09.1ce-1.111.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               docker = 17.09.1ce-1.111.amzn1
           Available: docker-17.12.0ce-1.129.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-updates)
               docker = 17.12.0ce-1.129.amzn1
```

Has anyone faced this error before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to install nvidia-docker2 with

`sudo yum install -y nvidia-docker2-2.0.3-1.docker17.12.1.ce.amzn1`

instead of just

`sudo yum install -y nvidia-docker2`

Maybe currently there's some version mismatch.